# Unbounded entire function - Little Picard Theorem and Identity theorem - contradiction?

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume we have an entire unbounded function $f(z)$.

My problem is the following contradiction I obtain:

We can conclude from Little Picard Theorem that the real part of $f(z)$ takes all real values (up to one). From the fact that the function is holomorphic everywhere I would conclude that the set $\{z\}$, where the $\Re f(z)$ is greater than zero is an open set, the same for the negative values. I also would think that at the boundary between the two $\Re f(z)=0$. But shouldn't then from identity theorem follow that $\Re f(z)=0$ everywhere (and accordingly our function is bounded)?

Comment: It's a bit unclear ,if you can provide more information." I also would think that at the boundary between the two ℜf(z)=0ℜf(z)=0. " About this??

Comment: Because the function is holomorphic everywhere, the $\Re f(z)$ is continuous, accordingly on the boundary between a region with positive  $\Re f(z)$ and negative $\Re f(z)$ it has to be satisfied: $\Re f(z)=0$.

Comment: Can you really apply the Little Picard  Theorem for  Re f(z). I don't think so

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana Basically, yes, you can: if $f$ is "surjective" on $\Bbb C$, then $\Re f$ is "surjective" on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @GSassatelli  but how can Ref be analytics so as to apply the theorem.

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana Picard applies to $f$. Corollary: $\Re f$ is surjective on $\Bbb R$ except at most one point. The theorem that does not apply to $\Re f$ in any sensible way is the identity theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Re f$ is never holomorphic (unless $f$ is constant), therefore the fact that it vanishes on a non-discrete closed set means nothing: the essential fact is that it shouldn't vanish on any open set.

In fact, the set $(\Re f)^{-1}(0)$ is ideally a nice "curve" in $\Bbb R^2$; the set $(\Im f)^{-1}(0)$ is, likewise, another nice curve. And sice *their itersection* $f^{-1}(0)$ is very likely to be a discrete set, the identity theorem will stay put and behave.